# ¿Cómo dar formato a una fecha en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

> Pregunta inspirada en [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552461/1595451)

Tengo un objeto de fecha en JavaScript y deseo imprimir en la consola en el siguiente formato: "14-Feb-2017". ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Este es el código que tengo:

```js
var fecha = new Date();
console.log(fecha);
```

Comment: En el idioma español son los meses en minúscula... ya que estás inspirado en los enlaces de meta... no se debería dar ejemplos generales? Pregunto...

Comment: Gracias por la observación @aldanux. En este caso se trata de un formato arbitrario y determinado de forma unilateral :P

Comment: En cuanto a si se deberían dar ejemplos generales, no me queda claro a que te refieres. Si es con respecto que la pregunta cumpla no sólo con los lineamientos de [ask] sino también con las expectativas mas exigentes, pues, sí, si debería pero esto ya raya en cuestiones filosóficas que es complicado abordar en los comentarios.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552461/1595451

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usa `toLocaleDateString` con `es` como local y `replace` con expresiones regulares para hacer los ajustes finos ya que usando sólo `toLocaleDateString` el resultado sería `14 feb. 2017`

Ejemplo:

```js
var opciones = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
var fecha = new Date()
  .toLocaleDateString('es',opciones)
  .replace(/ /g,'-')
  .replace('.','')
  .replace(/-([a-z])/, function (x) {return '-' + x[1].toUpperCase()});
console.log(fecha);
```

Answer (score 3):

Añado esta respuesta para los usuarios que prefieran usan la librería [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), muy popular a la hora de manejar fechas.

Los detalles del formato de salida puedes verlos [aquí](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

```js
//Usamos el idioma español
moment.locale('es');
let now= moment();

//formato por defecto
console.log(now)

//formato predefinido, hay más opciones (ver enlace anterior)
console.log(now.format('LL'));

//formato pedido por el OP (los meses en español empiezan por minúscula)
console.log(now.format('DD-MMM-YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Con información de [acá](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat):

```
const date = new Date()
const options = {
  year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric',
  hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric',
  hour12: true,
  timeZone: 'America/Mexico_City' 
};
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es-MX', options).format(date));

//imprimió:
//"13/5/2020 10:09:50 p. m."
```

Comment: El formato solicitado es dia en dos dígitos, guión, mes en tres letras, la primera mayúscula, las demás minúsculas, guion, año en cuatro dígitos. ¿Cómo se logra eso?